# the server tag is not well formed. do u know?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Please can anyone tell me why this happened?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Receta">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Receta1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "Handler1.ashx?PacientId=" + Eval("PacientId") %>' Height="200px" Width="200px"
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You mean the server tag is *not* well formed?

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo or not but you forgot to close the `<asp:Image>` tag.

Comment: yes "The server tag is not well formed" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your asp:Image is missing the ending `/>` to it.  That would definitely cause the error.